# Using the google street view image api v3 how do I Save street view images with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have a google street map and I would to create a button that allows to capture from the google images and for them to save it either to a document file so that they can add the information needed.

I understand that I have to use **[Street view](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview)** with all the details.

I first need my javascript to make sure that its capturing from the correct google street image and then i need to be able to save it to a specified spot all with a click of the one button created.

I have been looking around for many answers and all the ways do not seem to work in the way i need it to work.
I am new to the whole programming environment specifically with javascript.

I have tried adding in this:

```
$('#getStatic').click(function() {
                var maplatlong = map.getCenter().clone();
                maplatlong.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
                panoLatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(maplatlong.lat, maplatlong.lon);   

                $('#map_canvas').html('<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=' + panoLatLon.lat() + ',' + panoLatLon.lng() + '&maptype=' + map.getMapTypeId() + '&zoom=' + map.getZoom() + '&size=400x400&sensor=false">');
```

and then just attempting to try to alter it and then moving on to attempt add the code to get it show a saveto popup

Comment: Javascript has no access to the file system and saving images is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Streetview Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) to get an image, but use of that imagery is subject to the [Terms of Service/Use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), and you won't be able to do much with the image automatically because Javascript is sandboxed.

To save you looking it up, Terms 10.1.3 prohibit the storage of imagery and usage outside a web page.

Comment: I have been trying to use the streetview Image API but am not 100% sure on how to go about using it
Is there more of better example on how I go about using it? I cant have it at a set location as it would be many people selecting different areas.

Comment: Thanks too all for the info. I managed to sort out the issue of getting the street view images to show when I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Javascript has no access to the file system, therefore you cannot save a file with it.

2 - Saving images from Google Maps is not allowed. See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots

> Use of Google Maps imagery in printed materials **and offline media** is
>   subject to the Permission Guidelines published at:
>
> http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

you can request permission, but I don't think it's easy to obtain, unless you are a paying  business customer.

Comment: I am a paying business customer. How else would I then be able to get the images on the documents.

Comment: @user1538685, If you really have a business license then you have direct support from Google included in the price you're paying. Speak to your Google contact about it. I will not explain how to do it in an open forum because others, (non-business customers), could also take advantage of it and in any case, you'd need to request and obtain the permission first. ;-)

Comment: Thanks too all for the info. I managed to sort out the issue of getting the street view images to show when I clicked the button.I will not be placing the code info here though as how I had it sorted it out as @Marcelo had said that permission would have to be obtained first from google.

Comment: Keep in mind that since a few years ago JavaScript can save files thought many ways. The second point is still valid.